# Connecting to a wsdl in .net

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to connect the following service :

http://api.affiliatewindow.com/v4/AffiliateService?wsdl

I did the following :

1. Created a new empty web application (c# visual studio 2010)
2. Right Click on the solution -> add service reference
3. Pressed "GO"
4. Changed the name to AffWinAPI and pressed OK

I get the following error :
"Failed to generate code for the service reference 'AffWinAPI'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details."

I tried the solution suggested in the following and it still haven't worked for me.

[Service Reference Error: Failed to generate code for the service reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977560/service-reference-error-failed-to-generate-code-for-the-service-reference)

[What does this WCF error mean: "Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872865/what-does-this-wcf-error-mean-custom-tool-warning-cannot-import-wsdlporttype)

Any advice ?

Comment: possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872865/what-does-this-wcf-error-mean-custom-tool-warning-cannot-import-wsdlporttype

Comment: "Please check other error and warning messages for details." - Can you check if there are any inner exceptions? if so can you please share them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I got the same error but managed to add it as WebService

```
Add Service Reference/Advanced/Add Web Reference
```

If It asks to save, then save it to a folder and add reference using that file

Answer (score 1):

The way I've added web services in the past is via this method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx

Notice the use of the advanced button to reach a screen that says add web reference.  This will get you the asmx file and class reference you need to use your web service.

Answer (score 0):

I did the steps you described above, without any errors using VS2012. Check your internet connection and firewall configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In the Advanced dialog of Add Service Reference in Visual Studio, there is a check box "Reuse types in referenced assemblies". Can you un-check it and try adding the service again?