# Failed to generate code for service reference

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011

About a week ago I began trying to connect to an internal WCF web service. I received the error

> Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'DynamicsCom'. Please check other error and warning messages for details.

Unforunately the only other errors pointed towards the same basic problem: my solution was unable to bring down the namespace used by the WCF web service. In fact, the `Reference.cs` class is completely blank save for the auto-generated comment.

[image]

**Reference.cs**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18063
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Everything I've read on the internet suggests I got to `Configure Service Reference` and uncheck `Resuse types in referenced assemblies`. And while this does work, in bringing down the namespace used in the WCF web service, it unfortunatley creates a number of other conflicts.

Both my project and the web service namespace use the [Mircosoft CRM SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547453.aspx), and when I uncheck the `Reuse types in referenced assemblies` checkbox a number of namespace "ambiguities" occur (between the SDK dll referenced in the solution and the web service namespace).

My question is: is there a way to specifically debug the causes behind the namespace not being brought down from the web service? The common solution just seems like a blanket approach that doesn't always diagnose the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and resolved it as follows

> 1 . Remove DynamicsCom from your service refernces
>
> 2 . Clean the solution
>
> 3 . Re add service reference and give the same name "DynamicsCom"
>
> 4 . Right Click on DynamicsCom and go to Configure Service References
>
> 5 . Re Build the solution, it should work fine now

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to un-check/remove **Reuse types in referenced assemblies** checkbox by right-clicking on added service reference (select the name whatever you have given) and go to **Configure Service Reference**, see blow screenshot:

[image: Un-check this checkbox]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too, but I look the solution here : [Service Reference Error: Failed to generate code for the service reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977560/service-reference-error-failed-to-generate-code-for-the-service-reference)

It was caused by assembly version between server and client are different, so I uncheck some of my reference, rebuild the project and success.